# Print a table as plain text in @media print

Tags: html, css, web

I'm generally new with web design. I have a table of office locations on my website. It looks great on the website but I don't like the table format when printed, so I want to convert to plain text or list form for printing out. I've tried doing this in `@media print` but nothing is working so far.

I've tried making `table, th, td, tr {width: 100%}`, and I've tried forcing a line break after each `cell by adding "content: "\A"`

What else can I try?

Comment: Use classname or id of elements to make sure you overwrite previous rules. Try to add !important after each rule.

Comment: Want to post your table CSS? It'll be easier to help with a mock up

Comment: Please try to be even more specific on what you want to achieve. You will get much better answers when your problem is well defined. That said, you could get going by declaring `td, th { display: block; }` in your CSS.